# C - Printing array not working properly

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a code about inserting a grade / student number (KAS) / Name of the student into arrays

*And the after unknown number of inputs print them in the end*

> ISSUE: The issue of my project is that on printing results there are
>   some faulty elements on printing .

I tried to check every element that I inserted the exact time after I made an input ( with a `printf(...)` )
and everything seemed fine.

But still in the output some of them were wrong .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int grade[100] , KAS[100] ,x,spots = 0; // KAS = student number
    char name[spots][14], answer;

    printf("Please insert a grade : ");
    scanf("%d", &grade[spots]);    
    getchar();

    printf("Please add a KAS : ");
    scanf("%d",&KAS[spots]);
    getchar();

    printf("Please enter a name : ");
    scanf("%s",&name[spots]);
    getchar();

    printf("\nDo you want to add another value? y/n : ");
    scanf("%c",&answer);
    puts("");
    getchar();

    while(answer == 'y')
    {
        spots++;

            printf("Please insert another grade : ");
            scanf("%d", &grade[spots]);
            getchar();

            printf("Please add another KAS : ");
            scanf("%d",&KAS[spots]);
            getchar();

            printf("Please enter another name : ");
            scanf("%s",&name[spots]);
            getchar();


            printf("\nDo you want to add another value? y/n : ");
            scanf("%c\n",&answer);
            puts("");
            getchar();

            if(answer == 'n') 
            {
                break;
            }
    }
    puts("*****************************");
    for(x = 0; x < spots; x++)
    {
        puts("");
        printf("%d. Student's great : %d\n",x,grade[x]);
        printf("%d. Student's KAS : %d\n",x,KAS[x]);
        printf("%d. Student's name : %s\n",x,name[x]);
    }
    puts("\n*****************************\n");
}
```

Comment: Why those `getchar`s in your code?

Comment: Hint: think of something like `name[1][14]`, and check your definition....

Comment: `char name[spots][14]` --> `char name[100][14]`

Comment: @Mohit Jain because it skips scanf . I found that solution not to skip

Comment: @ehem Use extra space before " %s" and "%c" and remove all getchars. Then all would be good.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s",&name[spots]);` and this line: `scanf("%s",&name[spots]);` have a few problems: 1) insert a leading space in the format strings to enable skipping over left over white space in the input stream I.E. " %s"  2) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) (in these cases, it should always be `1`)  which would have caught the root problem with the code.

Comment: regarding this kind of parameter to scanf(): `&name[spots]`:  in C, referencing the name of an array degrades to the address of the array and `name[spots]` is a reference to an array of 14 bytes, so degrades to an address.  The scanf() needs an address for parameters, not an address of an address.  so the parameter should be: `name[spots]`.

Comment: this line: `char name[spots][14]` has `spots` set to 0, so this becomes a place holder and not an actual instance of an array.   Suggest: `char name[100][14]`

Comment: the code contains several 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using #defines or an enum to give the 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: for readability/understandability by us humans, only one statement per line and only one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: most of the calls to `getchar()` can be eliminated by inserting a leading space into the format strings as that leading space will consume an 'white space' left in the input stream

Comment: when using `scanf()` to input a string I.E. "%s" always place a max length modifier so the input buffer cannot be overrun.  Note since `scanf()` always appends a NUL byte to a input string, the max length must be 1 less than the actual buffer size.  With out the buffer size -1 or no max length modifier, the use can easily overrun the buffer, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when inputting the `yn` value, pass the result through `tolower()` before testing, so a `N` or `T` will be recognized.    Since the valid input is from a limited character set, check that the value is actually `y` or `n` before using it.

Comment: the posted code could be greatly shortened / simplified by merging the initial input with later inputs, all within a `do...while();` loop

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("%d. Student's great : %d\n",x,grade[x]);` you might want to replace `great` with `grade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char name[spots][14];         //as spots is 0 , it would be name[0][14]
 /* you would end up access invalid memory and cause UB */
```

You need to change this to -

```
char name[100][14];
```

And also while taking input in both statements inside and before loop-

```
scanf("%s",&name[spots]);
           ^ you don't need to use &
```

And also in the `for` loop use  `x <= spots` as loop condition.

Comment: So if I don't  declare a number instead of spots it automatically affects the results of of the other arrays in the end . But I just changed it to            " scanf("%c",&answer) , instead of leaving a space and looks preety nice >
**thanks**

Comment: @ehem Hmm ,you use `getchar()` so you wouldn't need space after `%c` .

Comment: thank you very much I just tried that without getchar() using spaces . Is getchar() heavier than spaces?

Comment: @ehem Its better than calling `getchar` so many times IMHO !!

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is alright. There are just a few mistakes there.
1. initialize array by writing `static int grade[ ]`...
2.Remove `getchar` before `if(answer == 'n')` statement.
3.The condition in for loop should be `x <= spots`. This is the reason that if you enter 2 student names, it prints name/record of only one student.
Hope it helped :)

Comment: thank you very much.1 / but static int at all the int things . 2 / why static ?

Comment: static initializes all the elements of array by 0. It should work with as well as without static but it was printing garbage value instead of grade when I removed static. If it works fine with your compiler then no need to static it.